# Capital gains tax applicability if buying a House abroad

Tags: united-kingdom, india, capital-gains-tax

I want to sell my House in India and bring that money to UK (living here for 2 years) to buy a house in UK. It will help me securing a loan by increasing the down payment I can make.

My question is, would I have to pay capital gain tax provided I am buying another house but not in India?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you need to pay Capital Gains tax in India. Further transfer of money out of India from Ordinary account requires some formalities / paperwork. A CA should be able to guide you.